# Does snap packages run similar to containers (docker / rkt etc) or use different underlying technology?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-containers

The technology(underlying mechanism) used  by containers like docker/rkt etc is a well documented and published. At a high level - they use namespace and cgroups for isolation and resource limiting respectively.

Now Snap (or snapd) is a kind of packaging, deployment and runtime (hope its a runtime too) developed for linux platforms / distros.
I am trying to understand what kind of tech snap uses at runtime and what sort of isolation (and resource limiting.. if provided) snap provides.

I have referred through wiki ([snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager)#Configurable_sandbox)) and few articles. But they don't explain the underlying technology to satisfaction.

Abstract from - [What You Need to Know About Snaps on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.howtogeek.com/670084/what-you-need-to-know-about-snaps-on-ubuntu-20.04/)

> at run time that the snap file is mounted on a block loop device. This
> allows the file’s internal SquashFS file system to be accessed.

and

> The application is executed in an encapsulated, ring-fenced way, so
> its files can’t interfere with those on your computer

**Any thoughts on the runtime internals (underlying technology of snap)... thanks for any answers !!**

--there is no tag for snap on sof yet. Quite sad :-( Request someone to create one.
snap could be a hit like containers some time in future.

Comment: Did you tried: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager)#Universal_Linux_packages ?

Comment: Yes, it's says about sqashfs and sandbox but nothing about runtime.

Answer (score 3):

There is a document in the Snap repository that goes into a bit more depth on the underlying mechanisms used by Snap:

https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/wiki/snap-confine-Overview

To give a quick overview here:

- Snap uses cgroups, as you surmised in your question
- There isn't really a "runtime"; cgroups are a feature of the Linux Kernel. The Kernel is the closest thing to a runtime used by Snap. Or, you could consider Snap itself to be the runtime.
- Snap is really only concerned with OS level isolation, eg libraries, binaries, etc.
- Snap doesn't really enforce device isolation or security.
- For security, Snap instead heavily relies on AppArmor and Seccomp.
- If you're on a distro that doesn't use AppArmor, Snaps have no security mechanisms.

Comment: somehow missed on this answer. Tx. so snap use only cgroups but not namespaces. cool